# [Windows 10]Problem escaping dollar sign contained in tablename for /copy command in psql

Tags: postgresql, powershell, terminal, syntax, escaping

I am trying to setup a shell script to insert data from .csv files into postgreSQL. As a first test I just tried rto do it in terminal command, and I am running into an issue because my table has a '$' in its name and I was not able to come up with the proper way to escape it so far.

My command look like this :

`psql -d trm -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres -c "\COPY ts_dev.tbl$trm_secndry_readings from 'FILEPATH' with delimiter ',' ;"`

I have made several test, with this command, if tablename='test1' the command works, but if tablename='prefix&test1' then the command fails as terminal is trying to parse what is after '$' as a variable name

So for example :

`psql -d trm -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres -c "\COPY schtest.prefix$name from 'FILEPATH' with delimiter ',' ;"`

`ERROR:  relation "schtest.prefix" does not exist`

I'm using Windows powershell.
[image: Initial command I'm using (works with a table that does not have a '$' in its name)]

[image: tentative at escaping (trying to escape just the '$' did not work either)]

Comment: What is your OS?

Comment: If you  want to **escape** the _$_, you can write it as `\$`, but you write that you want to have it as `&test1` and not as `$name`, so I wonder why you are writing the `$` in the first place. Please post exactly how you invoke your script, and what effect you would expect from your script.

Comment: @user1934428 I tried to escape $ with '\' it does not seem to work in this case, I think because of the double quote encapsulating the whole query.
&test1 and &name are example of a tablename that contains a dollar sign, in my example the tablename would be 'prefix$name'.
I edited my OP to add the actual command I'm using, except for the filename.

Comment: What is your shell?

Comment: @wildplasser Bad use of tags, I'm not at that shell phase yet, still just using command through terminal (on windows 10)

Comment: Your `psql` command is executed by the shell, its arguments are processed/expanded by the shell, so your quoting/escaping problem is a problem of the shell. (whatever shell it is ...)

Comment: The sentence _does not seem to work_ is meaningless, unless you provide in your posting also the input parameter you want to pass to your psql **and** what you expect PSQL to see.  Technically speaking, a `\$` passes the `$` sign verbatim as argument to the command, and I don't see such an escape character in your posting. From this, it is unclear to me what you are asking exactly.

Comment: If you have a terminal then you have a shell.  In CMD from my Windows 10, it doesn't do anything with dollar signs and  I can't reproduce your issue.  (It uses %foobar% to interpolate variables, not dollar signs.)

Comment: Half of your dollar signs seem to actually be ampersands.

Comment: Thanks for all feedbacks and question. Helped me realised how little I know about the topic...
I added a screenshot of the terminal with the command I'm using, I do not know how to determine what shell I'm using.

Comment: Now you have expressed in your posting that you are using _Powershell_. Before that, you had just tagged the question with _shell_, which means _POSIX shell_. Of course the previous comments and answer refer to POSIX shell and are irrelevant! You can't expect getting a good answer, if you provide incorrect/incomplete information.

Comment: @user1934428 I am very sorry about it, very new to this framework, hence incorrect use of tags... I'll edit it now.
Thanks for your patience.

Comment: @PaulGazagne: If you have already got an answer related to your misleading formulation of the question (as it is the case with the answer given by JGH), it is better to ask a new question. You may put a link in your question pointing to the new one, and explain why you did this. The basic rule is to never edit a question in a way which would invalidate  an existing answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In both POSIX-compatible shells such as `bash` and in PowerShell, `$` is a *metacharacter*, which - in unquoted use or inside `"..."` - requires *escaping* in order to be interpreted *verbatim* (in order to be passed through to a command as-is).

However, the *escape character* differs between these two shells:

- For POSIX-compatible shells it is `\`:

```sh
psql -d trm -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres -c "\COPY ts_dev.tbl\$trm_secndry_readings from 'FILEPATH' with delimiter ',' ;"
```

- For PowerShell it is `` ` `` (the so-called backtick; see [about_Special_Characters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Special_Characters)):

```sh
psql -d trm -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres -c "\COPY ts_dev.tbl`$trm_secndry_readings from 'FILEPATH' with delimiter ',' ;"
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add escaped double quotes around the table name

```
psql -d trm -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres -c "\COPY 
\"ts_dev.tbl$trm_secndry_readings\" from 'FILEPATH' with delimiter ',' ;"
```

Comment: Just tried this, did not work. The escaping symbol is not accounted for for some reason...

Comment: @JGH : Sadly, the OP revealed only now that he is not using shell, which makes your answer unsuitable.

Comment: @user1934428, that is unfortunate, but note that this answer wouldn't work in POSIX-compatible shells either, because the `$` would still be interpreted as the start of a variable reference. (My understanding of the question is that the `$trm_secndry_readings` part is to be treated _verbatim_ and passed through to `psql`).